# Programmatically alter an Excel sheet's row height

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How can I alter the row heights of all my non empty rows in my EXCEL sheet?
Thanks in advance,
w.

Comment: you mean by C# code? 
if so, simple place a foreach loop that checks all rows and set the rowsheight to your desired height (with a check wether the row is empty) untill it reaches the end of rows.

Answer (score 16):

```
...EntireRow.RowHeight = value;
```

Comment: Is that value in px or cm?

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be "Range.RowHeight" to modify the range's row height.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This only works for a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange`, which is not the object in question.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following:

```
        xlWorkSheet.Rows.RowHeight = height;
        xlWorkSheet.StandardWidth = width;
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
var SomeCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[1, 1];             
SomeCell.Value2 = "What was D.D. Eisenhower's Gettysburg Address?";
SomeCell.RowHeight = 32;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
MySheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Height = value;
```

Comment: `MySheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Height` seems to be a read-only property. Not able to set it.

Comment: Not true, just tried it. As long as your worksheet is not protected, you can set the .UsedRange.EntireRow.Height property.

Comment: It is readonly for me. "Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Height' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: I also find that "Height" is readonly; but "RowHeight" is not. zB, this compiles: _xlSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.RowHeight = 42;

Answer (score 5):

```
MySheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Height
```

Is ready only.
Unfortunately it won't work.

Try this:

```
NamedRange.RowHeight = X;
```

Please check MSDN for more info. :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: this link take you to a download page for retired documenation

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`sampleRange.Resize.RowHeight=x; //x's type must int`

Comment: This answer is currently in the low-quality queue. Please edit your answer and explain, why this solves the issue.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me. A minor clarification is that the value doesn't have to be an int, it can also be a double for instance.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can loop true all rows with a for loop something like this

```
  int i = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < column.Count(); i++)
        {
            worksheet.Row(i).Height = 100;
        }
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (XLWorkbook xLWorkbook = new XLWorkbook())
       {
         var wordsheet = xLWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(dtEmpDetail, status);
         wordsheet.Row(2).Height = 50;
         wordsheet.Range("A1:d2").Merge();
        }
```